# Is it possible to filter a data step on a newly computed variable?

Tags: sas, datastep

In a basic data step I'm creating a new variable and I need to filter the dataset based on this new variable.

```
data want;
    set have;

    newVariable = 'aaa';
    *lots of computations that change newVariable ;
    *if xxx then newVariable = 'bbb';
    *if yyy AND not zzz then newVariable = 'ccc';
    *etc.;

    where newVariable ne 'aaa';
run;
```

> ERROR: Variable newVariable is not on file WORK.have.

I usually do this in 2 steps, but I'm wondering if there is a better way.

( Of course you could always write a complex `where statement` based on variables present in `WORK.have`. But in this case the computation of `newVariable` it's too complex and it is more efficient to do the filter in a 2nd `data step` )

I couldn't find any info on this, I apologize for the dumb question if the answer is in the documentation and I didn't find it. I'll remove the question if needed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a subsetting `if` statement:

```
if newVariable ne 'aaa';
```

In general, `if <condition>;` is equivalent to `if not(<condition>) then delete;`. The `delete` statement tells SAS to abandon this iteration of the data step and go back to the start for the next iteration. Unless you have used an explicit `output` statement before your subsetting `if` statement, this will prevent a row from being output.

Comment: It's worth noting why this works when `WHERE` fails.  The `WHERE` clause is seen at compile time and applied to the stream of input records.  The `IF` is compiled statement and applied inline with the code.